# Create alias for production stage in Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

I've been using Capistrano to deploy my latest project. I have a fairly simple setup, with only a production stage (it created a staging one, but I don't use it).

I'm tired of typing `cap production deploy` to deploy my app. I really like how Rails handles this, with `rails c p` being the same as `rails console production`. I'd like to be able to type this:

```
cap p deploy
```

instead of the longer `production` version.

I've tried making a simple alias:

```
ln production.rb p.rb
```

Running `cap p deploy` gets through almost all of the deploy steps, then dies when running Rake migrations:

```
INFO [03d68697] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.2.2 do bundle exec rake db:migrate as ubuntu@mydomain.com
DEBUG [03d68697] Command: cd /var/railsapps/metasmoke/releases/20150904155532 && ( RAILS_ENV=p ~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.2.2 do bundle exec rake db:migrate )
DEBUG [03d68697]    Please require the stackprof gem falling back to fast_stack
DEBUG [03d68697]    
DEBUG [03d68697]    config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:
DEBUG [03d68697]    
DEBUG [03d68697]      * development - set it to false
DEBUG [03d68697]      * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
DEBUG [03d68697]      * production - set it to true
DEBUG [03d68697]    
DEBUG [03d68697]    rake aborted!
DEBUG [03d68697]    ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'p' database is not configured. Available: ["default", "development", "test", "production"]
DEBUG [03d68697]    /var/railsapps/metasmoke/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:248:in `resolve_symbol_connection'
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Cap takes arguments as production or staging or any other stages. Looking at the logs, rails is trying to find database settings for p which is not defined. May be you could create a db settings for p which might work but I'm not sure.

Comment: As a point of interest, your ln command is doing a hard link instead of a soft link. The latter is probably preferable. Additionally, I tend to just use prod as the deployment name, as it is short enough to be quick to type, and long enough for the meaning to be clear. Good luck!

Comment: @will_in_wi Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to add

```
set :rails_env, 'production'
```

to production.rb. Capistrano is inferring the Rails environment name from the stage name.